# Detect QUIC protocol from buffer in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, quic

I am having an app in Delphi that monitors UDP traffic. What is the proper way to detect when a QUIC protocol is used? I have the data in a TBytes buffer.

QUIC rfc: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9000

Comment: Have a read on [Manageability of the QUIC Transport Protocol, § 3.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-quic-manageability-16#section-3.1).

Comment: Thank you, very informative! There's no general method to distinguish the QUIC packets but maybe there is some workaround to achieve good detection rate.

Comment: You can upvote comments - consider taking the [tour]. Don't confuse "workaround" with shortcut or secret cheats - you won't be able to skip putting effort into it.

Comment: UDP traffic to port 443 is usually QUIC.

Comment: @AmigoJack can't upvote yet (new profile) but will do when I can.

Comment: Take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much of a positive match you're looking for, the effort varies between "walk in the park" and "a bit of a nightmare".

QUIC has a complex handshake, during which the encryption keys are derived, and then it moves into the fully-encrypted, application data phase. On top of this, the protocol is also designed to allow migration of endpoints during the exchange (such as a mobile device jumping between wifi and mobile data), so simply tracking IP addresses and ports isn't going to catch everything.

If all you want is basic detection of QUIC connections being initiated, then all you need to do is to look for the initial packets, which have a clear format, and are only obfuscated (not encrypted).

From [RFC9000](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9000#section-17.2.2):

```
17.2.2.  Initial Packet

   An Initial packet uses long headers with a type value of 0x00.  It
   carries the first CRYPTO frames sent by the client and server to
   perform key exchange, and it carries ACK frames in either direction.

   Initial Packet {
     Header Form (1) = 1,
     Fixed Bit (1) = 1,
     Long Packet Type (2) = 0,
     Reserved Bits (2),
     Packet Number Length (2),
     Version (32),
     Destination Connection ID Length (8),
     Destination Connection ID (0..160),
     Source Connection ID Length (8),
     Source Connection ID (0..160),
     Token Length (i),
     Token (..),
     Length (i),
     Packet Number (8..32),
     Packet Payload (8..),
   }
```

So a quick and dirty way of detecting a QUIC version 1 initial packet, is to check for the following (psuedocode):

```
( packet[ 0 ] & 0xf0 ) == 0xc0
packet[ 1 ] == 0x00
packet[ 2 ] == 0x00
packet[ 3 ] == 0x00
packet[ 4 ] == 0x01
```

If you want to go beyond this, it quickly gets exponentially more complicated.

I'd strongly recommend downloading and running [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and seeing for yourself what it looks like on the wire.